# A generator for multivariate normal variates in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, generator

I want to generate samples from a multivariate normal distribution with given mean and covariance, which, of course, is possible with `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`. But I want to generate a (philosophically) infinite stream of such things, and so I want to define a multivariate normal generator `mvn` so that `mvn.next()` produces another random vector with given mean and covariance. Of course, I can just keep calling `numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1)` but that is extremely inefficent  (I will be computing the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix on each call). Of course I can implement this from scratch myself, but it seems like something like this should already exist...

Comment: Why not call the `numpy` code with a large `size` and then dish out the values one by one?  When you exhaust the initial array, create another.

Comment: @hpaulj That is one of the things I had meant when I said I could do it myself. :) It is just that since morally a random sample is a generator (as in "random number generator") it would seem to make sense to package it that way...

Comment: Don't confuse the random package's use of `generator` with Python's use of the same term.

Comment: @hpaulj What makes you think I have confused them?

Answer (score 0):

Just to establish some ground truth, this is how one might implement it:

```
from collections.abc import Generator
import numpy as np

class multinorm(Generator):
    def __init__(self, themean, themat):
        self.eigs, self.cmat = np.linalg.eigh(themat)
        self.meanvec = themean
        self.thedim = self.meanvec.shape[0]
        self.themult = np.diag(np.sqrt(self.eigs))
    def send(self, ignored_arg):
        tmpvec = np.random.randn(self.thedim)
        return ( self.cmat.T @ self.themult) @ tmpvec + self.meanvec
    def throw(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        raise StopIteration
```